# Asymptote with Subfiles

Tags: asymptote, latexmk, subfiles

I am trying to get Asymptote (via the `asymptote` package) to work with `subfiles`. Currently, I can compile my main document just fine, but I cannot compile any of the subfiles individually. I am using the LaTeX Workshop extension of VSCode, if that is important.

Here is my hierarchy.

```
//test.tex
//.latexmkrc
//asymptote/
//dir/subfile.tex
```

Here are the contents of `test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{asymptote}
\renewcommand{\asydir}{asymptote}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}


hello
\begin{asy}
    settings.outformat = "pdf";
    unitsize(2cm);
    draw((0,0) -- (2,1));
\end{asy}
\subfile{dir/subfile}


\end{document}
```

Here are the contents of `subfile.tex`.

```
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}

\begin{document}


hi
\begin{asy}
    settings.outformat = "pdf";
    unitsize(2cm);
    draw((0,0) -- (3,1));
\end{asy}


\end{document}
```

Here are the contents of `.latexmkrc`.

```
sub asy {return system("asy -o \"$_[0]\" \"$_[0]\"");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

**How can I make it so that I can compile my subfiles individually?** If there's any further information or clarification that I can provide, please let me know!

Comment: You don't say what problem you encounter when you try to compile a subfile, but I suspect it is because when you try to compile from the top-level directory, pdflatex looks for a file `../main.tex` and doesn't find it, because the filename is relative to the compilation directory.  You need to compile from the lower level directory, which latexmk can do for you.  I suggest doing `latexmk -cd dir/subfile.tex`.  Alternatively set `$do_cd=1` in the `.latexmkrc` file.

Comment: @JohnCollins Thanks for your comment; ended up getting it working as follows. Fix the obvious error: my subfile indicated `../main` was the main file instead of `../test`! Fix the less obvious error (not sure why this worked, but it did repeatedly): (1) Have both `.latexmkrc` and an empty `asymptote/` directory in both the top-level and lower-level directory. (2) Compile `test.tex`. (3) Change `subfile.tex` to the `article` document class (copying over the preamble from `test.tex`, too) and compile `subfile.tex`. (4) Change `subfile.tex` back into a subfile. Voila.